# How to write a class constructor accepting both a list of values and each value separately

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

Assuming I have a list `lst = [1 2 3]` (as an example) and I want to write a class named `Vector`. When I pass this list to the `Vector`, i.e. when I instantiate `Vector(lst)`, then it should give the same object as when I want to pass this list as follows: `Vector(*lst)`. More precisely, how do I have to write the constructor when I want to have

`Vector(lst) == Vector(*lst)`?

It should be a 3-dimensional `Vector`. I tried

```
def __init__(self,x,y,z): # constructor
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
```

but this gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(Vector(examples[0]), Vector(*examples[0]))
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: `def __init__(self, *args):`? Then you can check whether the args tuple contains a single sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler won't try to figure out that a single argument should be unpacked; your options are to either put this logic in `__init__` itself (not recommended, since it gets tricky if you want an iterable argument to be used as-is and *not* unpacked), or define a class method as your alternate method of creating a `Vector`.

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def from_list(self, lst):
        # Raises an IndexError if the list is too short,
        # and silently ignores values in lst[3:]
        return Vector(lst[0], lst[1], lst[2])

coords = [1, 2, 3]
v1 = Vector(*coords)
v2 = Vector.from_list(coords)
```

Comment: How do I get Vector(...) == Vector(*...) equality? I have to write two __init__ modules?

Comment: You don't; why would you want them to be the same? If two things look different, ideally they should do different things.

Comment: I try to solve an exercise on "Codewars" with test_assertion: test.assert_equals(Vector(examples[0]), Vector(*examples[0])); moreover I should program the following: Vector([a,b,c]) # creates a new Vector from the supplied 3D array.
Vector(a,b,c) # same as above

Answer (score 1):

You could check within the `__init__`, although this isn’t advised as mentioned in chepner’s answer as this allows more ambiguous input to be given so you’ll need to do more checks. But if that’s what you want to do here’s a simple implementation:

```
class Vector:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
            args = args[0]
        self.x, self.y, self.z = args
```

---

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

print(Vector(*lst).__dict__)
print(Vector(lst).__dict__)
```

---

Output:

```
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```